# updating parameter value in aws parameter store using Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, updates, aws-ssm

I have a key stored as value in aws system manager(ssm). Is it possible to update the value using aws APIs?

For storing the key I am using the following API:

```
SsmClient ssmClientEUWest1 = SsmClient.builder().region(Region.EU_WEST_1).build();
ssmClientEUWest1.putParameter(PutParameterRequest.builder().value(key).name(<some constant name>).type("String").build());
```

As I store the **key** the first time it does create successfully. However as I call it again, it fails as `<some constant name>` is constant and hence it can't create duplicate names.

What I need is to update the **key**. I get this key as an input to my method and I just need to update the key in the store under the given constant name store.

I tried going through aws docs but couldn't find a solution. Docs suggest to use **tier** but that didn't prove useful either.

Answer (score 1):

Explored more and found out this can be done by setting `overwrite(true)`

So

```
PutParameterRequest.builder().value(key).name(<some constant name>).type("String").overwrite(true).build()
```

will do the job